# CURL - Connect explicit FTP over TLS

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ftp

I am trying to connect to FTP server using encryption as explicit FTP over TLS.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp.mydomain.com/orders'.$filename);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'uname:pwd');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 21);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
curl_exec ($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
```

I have to upload the file to this location, but while connecting to the server, it gives the error number 56 (response reading failed).
I am not sure whether I am using the correct options to explicitly connect FTP over TLS.

Comment: have you tried with a ready-made ftp program to access the server with the same properties as in your code?

Comment: What does `curl_error` return?

Comment: it returns with message "response reading failed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only you didn't enable TLS/SSL. You didn't even specify what protocol to use. And CURL defaults to HTTP. So your code fails because CURL tries to talk HTTP to FTP server.

To select FTP and force TLS/SSL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_FTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_ALL);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code -

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
```

Comment: Suggesting not to verify TLS/SSL certificate is a bad practice. Particularly without any explanation.